# Allow askers to rate their question in multiple categories

Tags: feature-request

Although askers are expected to ask good questions, many don't take the time to read the good question guidelines and/or aren't sure how much information to provide.

I suggest allowing askers to optionally rank their question on a scale from one to ten in several areas below:

- **Effort**. On a scale from 1-10, how much effort have you put into answering this question yourself? Sample values:

  - 1: No effort prior to asking this question
  - 3: have used search engines for a few minutes, but found nothing useful [a]
  - 5: have used search engines intensely, but found nothing useful [a]
  - 7: have contacted a library and/or offline resources
  - 9: have contacted experts in the field [b]

a: Include in your question what you found, and why it wasn't useful

b: Although you are welcome to ask your question here, you are unlikely to get better answers than provided by an expert.

- **Knowledge**. On a scale from 1-10, how well versed/learned do you feel in this field? Sample values:

  - 1: I am complete beginner
  - 3: I've studied it for less than year
  - 5: I've studied it for 1-3 years
  - 7: It is/was my college major and I have studied it fairly extensively
  - 9: I am a recognized expert in the field
- **Difficulty**. On a scale from 1-10, how difficult do you believe this problem is? Sample values:

  - 1: anyone can answer it [a]
  - 3: anyone with basic knowledge in the field can answer it [a]
  - 5: anyone who has studied the field can answer it [a]
  - 7: only an expert can answer it
  - 9: this is an unsolved problem in the field [b]
  - 10: the problem has been proven unsolvable [c]

a: Please consider using a search engine instead of posting a question

b: If the problem is unsolved in the field, it is unlikely that you will get an answer from stackexchange. However, you may receive guidance or resources.

c: If the problem is known unsolvable, you obviously won't receive an answer from stackexchange; however, you may receive guidance or resources. You may also use this ranking if you feel you have found a flaw in the insolubility proof.

- **Depth**. On a scale from 1-10, how detailed of an answer do you seek? Sample values:

  - 1: I just need a starting point
  - 3: I just want to know what words or phrases to type into search engines
  - 5: I'm looking for a helpful link that answers my question
  - 7: I'm looking for a complete answer
  - 9: I'm looking for a verbose, complete, worked-out answer, with sources and details
- **Urgency**. On a scale from 1-10, how urgent is this question. Sample values:

  - 1: I'm just casually curious and may not check back to see if I get an answer [a]
  - 3: I'm interested in the answer as a bit of trivia
  - 5: I'm studying this problem for an upcoming test/exam and would like some insight
  - 7: This question is part of a homework assignment I need to turn in soon [b]
  - 9: It's metaphorically life or death
  - 11: It's literally life or death. StackExchange is not an emergency response service. If there is immediate danger to life, limb, or property, please contact your local emergency services.

[a] We prefer questions be closed after they are answered. If you do not plan to look at the answer, please do not post a question

[b] Most sites have special rules regarding homework questions. Please review these rules before posting your question

- **Payment**. StackExchange is for volunteers to answer questions without the expectation of payment. If you are willing to pay, you may wish to visit a site where you can hire someone to answer your question. Some sample sites:

  - freelancer.com
  - fiverr.com
  - guru.com
  - mturk.com
  - upwork.com
  - topcoder.com
  - Your local craigslist.org may have a section where you can post questions/tasks for money

The list above isn't complete and may not be accurate. The links are representative and are not endorsed by StackExchange.

- **Additional Information**. Check any of the following that apply to your question:

  - My question is about recent events
  - The search phrases I use yield many irrelevant results, because the search phrases have other, more popular meanings

In addition to the 1-10 scale, each question would have a "no answer" default value and an "Other:" value with a freeform text field.

The text above these fields would read "filling out the following fields is optional, but may help you get a better and quicker answer to your question".

Of course, a good question should include many of the answers to these questions anyway, but it's easier for an asker to choose values, and it also allows answerers to focus on the questions they want to answer.

Comment: Is this question ironic?  Is there a joke that I'm just not getting here?

Comment: None of this information would be of any value to me in deciding whether to answer or not. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Also, *"We prefer questions be closed after they are answered"* What???

Comment: Why would we point people to sites where they can pay for help?

Comment: We can barely get people to do the basics, you want to add yet another super complicated layer onto it?

Comment: "I suggest allowing askers to optionally rank their question" - What types the author of a question from giving themselves the highest scores possible in every category?  "I'm looking for a complete answer" - What other type of answer is there other then a complete answer?.  The system you describe sounds absolutely horrible.

Comment: Note: Depth 5 questions would be asking for answers that would all be deleted via flagging and the low-quality posts review queue as link-only answers. Presumably shallower questions would have the same problem only more so.

Comment: There is one interesting idea in this post, though, and that is to have a separate section for including the details of research results. I don't think this proposal does that very well, but in theory a different approach to that basic idea might improve questions considerably, as many askers (and even many answerers/moderators) think SE requires "effort", as though it's some sort of payment system, when really all that's desirable is *context* to ground the answers in and make it easier for searchers to make use of the question.

Comment: I think today's blog post talks about something like this. I still believe something like this would really help new users.

Answer (score 8):

Please no. All these suggestions seem to miss the point of the site.

- **Effort**: The only reason this would be useful is to immediately weed out people that haven't tried anything. This answer could be lied about though (as with all the others), so it doesn't add anything of value. If they've tried anything, they need to say what in the question anyways so we know where they're starting from. It's little more than redundant information then to have that as a separate set of data as well.
- **Knowledge**: This is entirely subjective from the point of view of the asker. As the Dunning-Kruger effect (kind of) shows, you can't even rely on people's own perceived knowledge of a field. If you use years of experience as the indicators, as your example shows, that doesn't tell you knowledge, since people may learn at vastly different rates.
- **Difficultly**: Same as above. A new Python user may find a IndexOutOfBounds error insurmountable, whereas a seasoned user may find a significantly more challenging question easy. The asker's perceived difficulty of their question isn't useful information.
- **Depth**: This isn't up to the asker. It's up to the answerer to decide how much effort they're willing to put in for a given question. A 1 would just lead to lazy answers, while a 9 may discourage answers altogether. It also leads to "grey area" situations. Say two people ask the same question, but indicate different depth levels. Are they duplicates of each other? If not, does that mean there should then be allowed 9 different duplicates; one for each level? Also, by the definitions that you give, anything under a 6-7 likely isn't even on topic.
- **Urgency**: Again, entirely irrelevant. We don't care how urgent of a question it is, since that's completely besides the point of the site. A user a year from now doesn't care how urgent a question was when it was asked.
- **Payment**:  It could be argued that job soliciting should be added to the "Don't ask about" list in the [site tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) (although I don't know if it's a big enough problem to warrant that), but giving it as an option, just to then discourage it seems confusing. It seems more straightforward to just say outright that job soliciting isn't allowed.
- **Additional Information**: None of the suggested topics you give seem helpful. Why does a "recent events" option matter?

As mentioned in the comments, so many questions are already so lazy. Requiring more of people likely won't end well.